# Need help writing a regular expression to extract data from response in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, regex

I need to extract an ID from the response of an API call in JMeter. The response looks something like this:

"sessionId":"Edhgjhsbdjkkmsdsd-dlkmsdl.Mkhsdiufhskjndjsbsbd.iusdhfjsnkdnsd"
I only need to extract the last string between . and " i.e. iusdhfjsnkdnsd.

I've tried writing this regular expression:

"sessionId":"(.+?).(.+?).(.+?)"
I've set the template value to $3$ so only the third value is picked but it doesn't work. Nothing is captured using this regex. Please help me.

Comment: Hi tejebog328, highly recommend stackoverflow.com as another place for seeking answers to [jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jmeter?tab=Newest) or [regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex?tab=Newest) questions.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, all you need to do is to escape dots with backslashes like:

```
"sessionId":"(.+?)\.(.+?)\.(.+?)"
```

because dot is a [meta-character](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html#meta_chars) which means "any character" and if you want JMeter's regex engine to treat is as a dot - you need to escape it properly.

Also you can consider using [Boundary Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-boundary-extractor), all you need to do is to set "left" and "right" boundaries and JMeter will capture everything in-between

Answer (score 0):

Dimitri T correctly pointed out the [dot has a special meaning](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/50697/27414)

Try to minimise use of the `.+` pattern, some suggestions: [regexr.com explains](https://regexr.com/71jna)

```javascript
> const cookieItem = '"sessionId":"Edhgjhsbdjkkmsdsd-dlkmsdl.Mkhsdiufhskjndjsbsbd.iusdhfjsnkdnsd"'
> console.log( cookieItem.match(/\w+/g).at([-1])
iusdhfjsnkdnsd
```

here are some equivalents:
`console.log(cookieItem.match(/(?<=[.-])\w+(?=")/g).at(-1) );` returns the last segment.
`console.log(cookieItem.match(/\w+(?="$)/gm).at(-1) );` anchors to the end of the string.

[The Mozilla JavaScript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) for `.match(str, pattern)`